# Python unittest: how to run only part of a test file?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a test file that contains tests taking quite a lot of time (they send calculations to a cluster and wait for the result). All of these are in specific TestCase class.

Since they take time and furthermore are not likely to break, I'd want to be able to choose whether this subset of tests does or doesn't run (the best way would be with a command-line argument, ie "`./tests.py --offline`" or something like that), so I could run most of the tests often and quickly and the whole set once in a while, when I have time.

For now, I just use `unittest.main()` to start the tests.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The default `unittest.main()` uses the default test loader to make a TestSuite out of the module in which main is running.

You don't have to use this default behavior.

You can, for example, make three [unittest.TestSuite](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestSuite) instances.

1. The "fast" subset.

   ```
   fast = TestSuite()
   fast.addTests(TestFastThis)
   fast.addTests(TestFastThat)
   ```
2. The "slow" subset.

   ```
   slow = TestSuite()
   slow.addTests(TestSlowAnother)
   slow.addTests(TestSlowSomeMore)
   ```
3. The "whole" set.

   ```
   alltests = unittest.TestSuite([fast, slow])
   ```

Note that I've adjusted the TestCase names to indicate Fast vs. Slow.  You can subclass
unittest.TestLoader to parse the names of classes and create multiple loaders.

Then your main program can parse command-line arguments with [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) or [argparse](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) (available since 2.7 or 3.2) to pick which suite you want to run, fast, slow or all.

Or, you can trust that `sys.argv[1]` is one of three values and use something as simple as this

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = eval(sys.argv[1])  # Be careful with this line!
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Comment: nice, now if it only it were this easy in c++ land for my algorithm stress tests :)

Comment: @MattJoiner: I know a friend who used Python and `ctypes` to write and run unit tests against C/C++ code. Anyway, this is off-topic to this question.

Comment: I had to modify the code to get this to work. Here is what worked for me:

`test_class = eval(sys.argv[1])`

`suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(test_class)`

`unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)`

Comment: Small change: I think it should be addTest, not addTests. Docs say addTests is for iterable of tests, while addTest is for adding a TestCase class

Answer (score 102):

To run only a single specific test, you can use:

```
python -m unittest test_module.TestClass.test_method
```

More information is [here](http://pythontesting.net/framework/specify-test-unittest-nosetests-pytest/).

Comment: I'm debugging my test cases, so this method is way more helpful than the accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: This also works with more than one test at a time. Just make sure they are space delimited like so: 

`python -m unittest test_module.TestClass.test_method test_module.TestClass.test_method2`. So even if you have a handful of related test cases to run, this can still be really useful.

Answer (score 25):

I'm doing this using a simple `skipIf`:

```
import os

SLOW_TESTS = int(os.getenv('SLOW_TESTS', '0'))

@unittest.skipIf(not SLOW_TESTS, "slow")
class CheckMyFeature(unittest.TestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        …
```

This way I need only decorate an already existing test case with this single line (no need to create test suites or similar, just that one `os.getenv()` call line in the beginning of my unit test file), and as a default this test gets skipped.

If I want to execute it despite being slow, I just call my script like this:

```
SLOW_TESTS=1 python -m unittest …
```

Answer (score 14):

Actually, one can pass the names of the test case as sys.argv and only those cases will be tested.

For instance, suppose you have

```
class TestAccount(unittest.TestCase):
    ...

class TestCustomer(unittest.TestCase):
    ...

class TestShipping(unittest.TestCase):
    ...

account = TestAccount
customer = TestCustomer
shipping = TestShipping
```

You can call

```
python test.py account
```

to have only account tests, or even

```
$ python test.py account customer
```

to have both cases tested

Comment: Works for me in Python 2.7.11 and 3.5.1. The names are the attributes that are available on the module. `account = TestAccount` is not needed, you can also use `python test.py TestAccount`.

Comment: To extend my previous comment (and stating the obvious): This command-line parameter works provided that `unittest.main()` is called. E.g. `if __name__ == '__main__': unittest.main()`

Answer (score 11):

You have basically two ways to do it:

1. Define your own suite of tests for the class
2. Create mock classes of the cluster connection that will return actual data.

I am a strong proponent of he second approach; a unit test *should* test only a very unit of code, and not complex systems (like databases or clusters). But I understand that it is not always possible; sometimes, creating mock ups is simply too expensive, or the goal of the test is really in the complex system.

Back to option (1), you can proceed in this way:

```
suite = unittest.TestSuite()
suite.addTest(MyUnitTestClass('quickRunningTest'))
suite.addTest(MyUnitTestClass('otherTest'))
```

and then passing the suite to the test runner:

```
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

More information on the python documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#testsuite-objects

Comment: Yes, I know about mock objects, but I think this will be too complicated. The python doesn't connect directly to the cluster, it goes through a series of bash scripts whose behavior I need to test. So, I would need to make "mock scripts" that would behave the same as the real ones, except for that last connection part, but then I would have to maintain the two at the same time and make sure that they are equivalent for what I want to test...

Thank you for your answer about the test suites, I chose the answer from S. Lott because it is a bit more detailed, but it's basically the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

Since you use `unittest.main()` you can just run `python tests.py --help` to get the documentation:

```
Usage: tests.py [options] [test] [...]

Options:
  -h, --help       Show this message
  -v, --verbose    Verbose output
  -q, --quiet      Minimal output
  -f, --failfast   Stop on first failure
  -c, --catch      Catch control-C and display results
  -b, --buffer     Buffer stdout and stderr during test runs

Examples:
  tests.py                               - run default set of tests
  tests.py MyTestSuite                   - run suite 'MyTestSuite'
  tests.py MyTestCase.testSomething      - run MyTestCase.testSomething
  tests.py MyTestCase                    - run all 'test*' test methods
                                           in MyTestCase
```

That is, you can simply do

```
python tests.py TestClass.test_method
```

Answer (score 6):

I found another solution, based on how the `unittest.skip` decorator works. By setting the `__unittest_skip__` and `__unittest_skip_why__`.

**Label-based**

I wanted to apply a labeling system, to label some tests as `quick`, `slow`, `glacier`, `memoryhog`, `cpuhog`, `core`, and so on.

Then run `all 'quick' tests`, or `run everything except 'memoryhog' tests`, your basic whitelist / blacklist setup

**Implementation**

I implemented this in two parts:

1. First add labels to tests (via a custom `@testlabel` class decorator)
2. Custom `unittest.TestRunner` to identify which tests to skip, and modify the testlist content before executing.

Working implementation is in this gist:
https://gist.github.com/fragmuffin/a245f59bdcd457936c3b51aa2ebb3f6c

(A fully working example was too long to put here.)

The result being...

```
$ ./runtests.py --blacklist foo
test_foo (test_things.MyTest2) ... ok
test_bar (test_things.MyTest3) ... ok
test_one (test_things.MyTests1) ... skipped 'label exclusion'
test_two (test_things.MyTests1) ... skipped 'label exclusion'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.000s

OK (skipped=2)
```

All `MyTests1` class tests are skipped, because it has the `foo` label.

`--whitelist` also works

Answer (score 4):

I created a decorator that allows for marking tests as slow tests and to skip them using an environment variable

```
from unittest import skipIf
import os

def slow_test(func):
    return skipIf('SKIP_SLOW_TESTS' in os.environ, 'Skipping slow test')(func)
```

Now you can mark your tests as slow like this:

```
@slow_test
def test_my_funky_thing():
    perform_test()
```

And skip slow tests by setting the `SKIP_SLOW_TESTS` environment variable:

```
SKIP_SLOW_TESTS=1 python -m unittest
```

Comment: I couldnt edit this for you, but your import should say `import skipIf` instead of `import skip`

Answer (score 2):

Or you can make use of the `unittest.SkipTest()` function.  Example, add a `skipOrRunTest` method to your test class like this:

```
def skipOrRunTest(self,testType):
    #testsToRun = 'ALL'
    #testsToRun = 'testType1, testType2, testType3, testType4,...etc'
    #testsToRun = 'testType1'
    #testsToRun = 'testType2'
    #testsToRun = 'testType3'
    testsToRun = 'testType4'              
    if ((testsToRun == 'ALL') or (testType in testsToRun)):
        return True 
    else:
        print "SKIPPED TEST because:\n\t testSuite '" + testType  + "' NOT IN testsToRun['" + testsToRun + "']" 
        self.skipTest("skipppy!!!")
```

Then add a call to this skipOrRunTest method to the very beginning of each of your unit tests like this:

```
def testType4(self):
    self.skipOrRunTest('testType4')
```

Comment: You could use skip test decoration e.g. @unittest2.skipUnless(runslowtests(),"slow test")

Answer (score 1):

Look into using a dedicated testrunner, like *py.test*, *Nose* or possibly even *zope.testing*. They all have command-line options for selecting tests.

Look for example at [Nose](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose/1.3.0).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think it's a bit overkill, so I chose the TestSuites one.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: You are incapable of using Google to find the new URL?

Comment: @LennartRegebro Your answer should stand alone without links needed to complete it. Links should be supplemental information. As it stands, your answer does not answer the question. Not to mention the useful part of the answer 404s.  See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: It answers the question in a useful manner (namely pointing out that if you want this kind of functionality, using a framework that extends unittest is the best way to go), the link is supplemental information. I've fixed the link.

Answer (score 1):

I tried [S.Lott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068246/python-unittest-how-to-run-only-part-of-a-test-file/1068366#1068366):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = eval(sys.argv[1])  # Be careful with this line!
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

But that gave me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functional_tests.py", line 178, in <module>
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/runner.py", line 151, in run
    test(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 188, in __init__
    testMethod = getattr(self, methodName)
TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

The following worked for me:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_class = eval(sys.argv[1])
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(test_class)
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way to select the test_* methods that I only want to run by adding an attribute to them. You basically use a metaclass to decorate the callables inside the TestCase class that have the StepDebug attribute with a unittest.skip decorator. More information is in:

*[Skipping all unit tests but one in Python by using decorators and metaclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121111/skipping-all-unit-tests-but-one-in-python-by-using-decorators-and-metaclasses)*

I don't know if it is a better solution than those above I am just providing it as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Goal: Get a set of test files together so they can be run as a unit,
but we can still select any one of them to run by itself.

Problem: the discover method does not allow easy selection of a single test case to run.

Design: see below. This *flattens* the namespace so can select by TestCase class name, and leave off the the "tests1.test_core" prefix:

```
./run-tests TestCore.test_fmap
```

Code

```
  test_module_names = [
    'tests1.test_core',
    'tests2.test_other',
    'tests3.test_foo',
    ]

  loader = unittest.defaultTestLoader
  if args:
    alltests = unittest.TestSuite()
    for a in args:
      for m in test_module_names:
        try:
          alltests.addTest( loader.loadTestsFromName( m + '.' + a ) )
        except AttributeError as e:
          continue
  else:
    alltests = loader.loadTestsFromNames( test_module_names )

  runner = unittest.TextTestRunner( verbosity = opt.verbose )
  runner.run( alltests )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only thing that worked for me.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(argv=sys.argv, testRunner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2))
```

When I called it though I had to pass in the name of the class and test name. A little inconvenient since I don't have class and test name combination memorized.

```
python ./tests.py class_Name.test_30311
```

Removing the *class* name and test name runs all the tests in your file.  I find this *much* easier to deal with than the built-in method since I don't really change my command on the CLI. Just add the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer trying to figure out how to just run specific *classes* of tests; for example,

```
class TestCase1(unittest.TestCase):
    def some_test(self):
        self.assertEqual(True, True)

class TestCase2(unittest.TestCase):
    def some_other_test(self):
        self.assertEqual(False, False)
```

I wanted a quick way to comment out `TestCase1` or `TestCase2` that didn't involve me sweep-selecting 100+ lines of code, and I eventually landed on this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tests = []
    tests.append("TestCase1")
    # tests.append("TestCase2")
    unittest.main(defaultTest=tests)
```

It just uses `unittest.main()`'s `defaultTest` argument to specify which test classes to run.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I run each of my test functions manually.  Say my test class looks like this...

```
class TestStuff(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1():
    def test2():
```

Then I run this...

```
t = TestStuff()
t.test1()
t.test2()
```

(I use the Spyder IDE for data analysis, this might not be ideal for IDEs with a slicker testing tools)