# Unit testing in Python

Tags: python, python-unittest

This is my first project in Python and I have just learnt the [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) framework. The test module runs well when I do `python test_module.py` but when I want to execute a certain class or a method as said in the documentation using:

```
python -m unittest test_module.TestClass.test_method  # or even just test_module
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_module'
```

The directory where I run the command contains `graphm_test.py` (I also tried to change the name to `test_graphm.py`), with `class graphm_test(unittest.TestCase):` and methods all starting with `test_*` and here is the command I run on the terminal:

```
python -m unittest test_graphm.py
```

I could not find a similar problem to this anywhere, it would be great to know the reason behind the error and how to run a certain class inside the module or a certain method

Comment: Consider using nosetest as your test runner instead.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971735/running-single-test-from-unittest-testcase-via-command-line and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068246/python-unittest-how-to-run-only-part-of-a-test-file

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues: you are not calling the correct module name, and you are using the extension `.py`.

So you need to be in the folder with your `graphm_test.py` file, and run:

```
python -m unittest graphm_test
```